# How does one show quasiconcavity?

Tags: functions

Is there a general method, or does one have to get creative in some way?

For example, let $$f(x,y,z) = 3\sqrt{x + y + 2z}$$

I've tried looking at the definition, but I am not sure what to do with the sums of $ts$ and $(1-t)s$ under a square root?

Or are there perhaps equivalent properties that are easier to show?

Comment: How is this defined when $x+y+2z <0$?

Comment: It is only defined for positive $x,y,z$. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that the level sets are convex.

Let $\alpha \ge 0$, then
$f^{-1}(\alpha) = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}_+^3 | x+y+2z \le ({\alpha\over 3})^2\}$.

It is straightforward to check that $\mathbb{R}_+^3$ and sets of the form
$\{ (x,y,z)  | x+y+2z \le t \}$ are convex, hence the function is quasiconvex.